# Do not show all post from all categories, just show posts from category in current loop

Tags: categories, loop

I have following loop that show all children categories of a parent category(id = 3)
The first loop i want to show every child category in a parent div (destination-tours)
The second loop i want to show every post from current child category in a child div (des-item)
But the result shows all posts in every parent div. So where's the bug?
Here's my code
Thank you for reading!

```
    <div id="<?php echo $child_category->term_id; ?>" class="destination-tours">
        <h1 class="tour-title"><?php echo category_description(3); ?></h1>

        <?php
            $des_post = new WP_Query('post_type=tour', array('cat='.$child_category->term_id));
            while($des_post->have_posts()) : $des_post->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="des-item">
            <div class="tour-img col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="tour-des col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="tour-detail col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                <h1>FROM
                    <?php
                        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'currency')[0];
                        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price')[0];
                    ?>
                </h1>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'length')[0]; ?> day tour</p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongfully handling the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) parameters. You can either use a *query string* type input or an *array based* one. Personally I much prefer the array type, so my example uses it:

```
$category_id = (int) $child_category->term_id;
$des_post_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'tour',
  'cat'       => $category_id
);
$des_post = new WP_Query( $des_post_args );
```

Comment: My pleasure! @Zee